# Python Xarray integrate a 2D array along datetime dimension

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have very large 2D variables in Xarray.  They have the form: counts(time, altitude) where time is a numpy datetime every 10 seconds, altitude is float, counts are floats with occasional NaNs.

I would like to reduce the resolution to every 15 minutes by summing or averaging over the corresponding columns.

Likewise, I would like to do the same along the rows of counts in the altitude dimension.

I would appreciate some advice on how this should be done in Python (I'm still on the learning curve for Python).

Comment: Hi there! welcome to stack overflow! Feel free to take the [tour] and check out the guide to [ask]. In order to answer a question, we'll need more info from you about your specific problem, ideally structured as a [mre]. Please show us what your data looks like, and walk us through what you've tried and specifically where you're stuck. As a jumping off point, see xarray's [`resample`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html) docs and the user guide section on [time series data](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the resample method from xarray (see examples in docs https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html).

There are named time offsets based on pandas (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

For example, a yearly mean based on a daily database should be something like this:

```
ds.resample(time='Y').mean('time')
```

In your case it should be:

```
ds.resample(time='15min').mean('time')
```

where time is the time variable in your dataset and '15min' is the named time offset from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects